Would a System that Detects Catastrophic Oil Leaks in Non-Pressurized General Aviation be Necessary?
I’m currently enrolled in a college course where my group is tasked with designing a product. Our idea is a catastrophic oil leak detection system for non-pressurized general aviation aircraft, proposed by a team member. However, I’m new to aviation and am trying to gauge the actual necessity and feasibility of such a system.
I’ve conducted interviews and sent out a survey, but I’m uncertain if our product idea addresses a real need in the industry. I tried to research this topic online but couldn’t find much information regarding catastrophic oil leaks in general aviation. I’m not sure if this is the right place to ask, as I’ve reached out to others without much success. I apologize if my post is unclear.
Can anyone provide insights into the following?

The frequency and impact of catastrophic oil leaks in non-pressurized aircraft.
Existing solutions or technologies for detecting these leaks.
Any regulatory or safety considerations that may support the need for such a detection system.

I appreciate any information or thoughts you can share.

How is this different from a low oil pressure light? Whether the oil leaked out or the oil pump failed, the result is the same: the engine will cease to run shortly.

The standard oil pressure indicator basically does exactly this, along with providing information that's useful beyond detecting catastrophic leaks. Those are present in basically every aircraft.

A catastrophic oil leak will come from 2 sources: Front crankshaft seal blowing out, or, an oil cooler or cooler supply hose fails, or some other oil line like a turbo supply line. A front crank seal, you'll know it right away because you won't be able to see out the windshield with all the oil on it. That leaves the cooler and hoses. Instead of a leak detector, I'd design a fluid fuse at the engine outlet similar to the hydraulic fuses used on landing gear to prevent loss of hydraulic fluid following a downstream rupture. The fuse would have a cockpit indicator to announce that it's operated.

@user71659 If you have an internal leak under a cowling, you won't get a cockpit indication on pressure until the oil pump pickup is exposed, at which point 90% of the oil will have been dumped overboard. You would expect to see a slow increase in temperature as the oil volume is reduced, but this wouldn't be obvious right away.
